# Rails console returns nil for column that contains a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am developing an app that uses the CanCanCan gem, which is an update of Ryan Bates' CanCan, for authorization. CanCan uses a `:role` attribute to assign Abilities.  My User model also uses STI, containing Admins and another role called "Agents."  To avoid redundancy, and keep things DRY, I utilize the `:role` attribute as the `inheritance_column` as well.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password

    attr_reader :role

  scope :profile, -> { includes(:address, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :email)}
  scope :office_use, -> { includes(:username, :role, :type, :last_name, :first_name,     :password_digest)}

  self.inheritance_column = :role  


  def self.roles
     %w[Admin Agent]
  end
```

In the Rails console, I create a new user. I removed the choice to assign roles from the input form, figuring I'd create Admins manually since there won't be many, so it enters the default, "Agent":

```
   (63.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 2, username: "ff001", role: "Agent", password_digest:     "$2a$10$osm9oEB51GKilUkX64sV7eMlt6pEfuzEfKIf3gRo/az...", last_name: "Flintstone", first_name: "Fred", address: nil, city: nil, state: nil, zip: nil, phone: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2015-01-01 19:01:11", updated_at: "2015-01-01 19:01:11"> 2.1.4 :019 >
```

Retrieving the row:

```
> User.last
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`   ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Agent id: 2, username: "ff001", role: "Agent", password_digest: "$2a$10$osm9oEB51GKilUkX64sV7eMlt6pEfuzEfKIf3gRo/az...", last_name: "Flintstone", first_name: "Fred", address: nil, city: nil, state: nil, zip: nil, phone: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2015-01-01 19:01:11", updated_at: "2015-01-01 19:01:11"> 2.1.4 :020 >
```

Now a query for the `:role` attribute:

```
 > User.last.role
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`   ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

This happens ONLY in the case of the role attribute--all, other columns when queried return their correct value.  The role is used not only for authorization in the app, but also for routing to different resources for Admins.  Since ActiveRecord is returning nil in the controller, my routing is not working properly either.  I haven't even reached the point where authorization comes into play. Until the routes work correctly, authorization is kinda moot.

Why would this be happening? The `:role` attribute is the only one behaving this way.

Comment: In the first panel, the :type attribute is still listed, but I had already removed it in a migration, and it is no longer active in the controller. Shouldn't affect anything but I'll try again.

Comment: Re-added the `:type` attribute (single-table-inheritance default) and updated the table rows.  Now both the `:role` & `:type` attribute values get returned in the console.  Why would that be?  Some issue/conflict with the CanCanCan gem?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `attr_reader :role` - this should already be outlined in your schema. Then do `User.last.role` in your console, and you'll get back what you've assigned.